# loop each row item in a listview then evaluate which radiobutton isChecked

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, radio-button

I am creating a WPF application that allows the user to take a quiz then submit their answers. I have a ListView which displays 2 Label and 4 RadioButton for each row. The first Label is for the item number. The second Label is the question for the current item. The 4 RadioButton are the choices that the user may select. The items in my ListView are binded from a class that I created which is named "Question". It has 7 properties, namely: number, problem, choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4, and correct_answer. Only the property "correct_answer" is not displayed in the ListView. If I click the Submit Button, I want to know which RadioButton isChecked for each row item in the ListView for me to be able to know if they answered each item correctly and provide them with a score on how many items they got right. Please advise.

Below is my xaml

```
    <ListView x:Name="list_question" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Content="{Binding number}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Label>
                    <Label Content="{Binding problem}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Label>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <RadioButton Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding choice1}"></RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Content="{Binding choice3}"></RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton Grid.Row="2" Content="{Binding choice2}"></RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  Content="{Binding choice4}"></RadioButton>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>            
    </ListView>
```

My Button click event handler

```
    private void btn_submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in list_question.Items)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using radio button to select one choice out of 4 then first of all you need to put same name for all options then will help u to get selected choice as well as allow end user to select only one option.

Comment: <RadioButton HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsAM}" GroupName="{Binding ID}" ></RadioButton>

Comment: Okay. I added your code to the 4 RadioButton element. I'm not such an expert at this.I just started using Data Binding. Please expound more on IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsAM}" GroupName="{Binding ID}"

Comment: IsChecked To select if your condition matched.

Comment: GroupName is help to group radio button for single selection out of group radioButton members.

Comment: what is Path=IsAM? and do I add the property ID to my class?

Comment: Its Bool value if its true then this radio button will be selected. Leave it if its not much useful for you now.

Comment: Still Confused. If the user clicks the Submit Button, I want to be able to loop through each row item in the ListView then evaluate if the user checked the correct RadioButton for me to provide them with a score on how many items they got correct.

Comment: Try this [Link](http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/143776/How-to-save-record-RadioButton-inside-ListView-in-to-database-in-ASPNet/)

Comment: The link is for asp.net & I think we don't have the same problem. Thanks anyway.